# Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin

On the website https://code.google.com/apis/console I have registered my application, set up generated **Client ID:** and **Client Secret** to my app and tried to log in with Google.
Unfortunately, I got the error message:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI

scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
access_type=offline
approval_prompt=force
client_id=generated_id
```

What does mean this message, and how can I fix it?
I use the gem **omniauth-google-oauth2**.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, note that you can debug this issue by accessing a URL like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}` in a browser, instead of running your entire app to test.

Comment: I have noticed, google automatically bind redirect_uri in double quotes in ( redirect_uri= "whatever") above url, and results this error. If I remove this double quotes, I am able to go through next screen. Now, how can we evade this double quotes, since it is automatically redirected by google itself.

Comment: @JackM response_type shouldn't be equal to `code`? what's the `token`?

Answer (score 605, accepted):

The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your `client ID` & `client secret` there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

EDIT: (From a highly rated comment below) Note that updating the google api console and that change being present can take some time. Generally only a few minutes but sometimes it seems longer.

Comment: Ran into a similar problem, and wanted to note that updating the google api console and that change being present can take some time.  Generally only a few minutes but sometimes it seems longer.

Comment: Open a private/incognito window in your browser, and try again.  Sometimes this fixes the caching issue.

Comment: google has no options for a redirect uri in the google console in the "Api & Auth > Credentials" donsn't matter if I create a new Client Id or generate a new key, there is simply no way to specify the redirect uri from the google console.

Comment: the only way I was able to get the redirect option was via http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976227/3338098  this solved all of my problems

Comment: What if you have a very long dynamic url which may change, I am having issues where the redirect uri doesn't seem to be matching I believe due to the dynamic variables used to navigate to the page and session values

Comment: The "Edit Settings" button is only available for web application. You need to create "Client ID for web application" if you can't find the setting.

Comment: Anyone struggling to find where to set redirect urls in the new console: APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs -> Click the link to find all your redirect urls

Comment: "Generally only a few minutes but sometimes it seems longer". What is the longest people had to wait? I've waited about an hour now and it still doesn't work and I am 100% sure I've set everything up correctly.

Comment: I'm just fade up with these mistakes which present no logic at all . i mean what is difference between http:// www. myweb.com and http:// www.myweb.com / . should not these things be handled at their side :( truely disappointing

Comment: and if they are taking time for some reason to implement change , then there must be some kind of notification to developer so that we could know whether change is made or not :(

Comment: The other thing to note is that there is a delay between setting the redirect url(s) in the credentials screen and when they take affect and allow the login flow to work.  In my case it was a couple of minutes.

Comment: The type of credentials also matter.  "Other" won't give you an option to add "Authorised redirect URIs", while "Web application" does.

Comment: The interface on google is so bad.  You can press save and it doesn't save.  Seems like you need to hammer the save button.  Refresh the page to check the urls have been added properly to the list.

Comment: "list of redirect URIs" is no longer in the console.  Can anyone describe a way to create a redirect URI in the console?

Comment: @Yar, i had the same issue and solved it by following these instructions. I hope you don't have the issue anymore, but maybe that'll help someone else. https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp#using-your-own-credentials.

Comment: Please note that the redirect uris are case sensitive :(

Comment: I started getting this error after changing my redirect uri (even though I updated it in the google API console to exactly match the redirect uri I was using). After 20 hours I was still getting this error, so I simply created a new OAuth client id in the console and that worked immediately.

Comment: I am having this same error and I believe is due to the website domain be different to the email domain. Could this be the case?

Comment: I had the same problem on the reactjs app. I added domain http://lvh.me:3000 for my localhost in authorized url on google developer console. It is working fine.

Comment: Also worth noting that the 'http' part of the URL must match in both the local script and the GCP api console. You will experience an error if one is 'http' and the other is 'https' for example. Seems obvious but easy to overlook.

Comment: Just note that the Google API console is *incredible* sensitive to the URL you enter. As noted above it's case-sensitive. It's also trailing-slash sensitive. Just treat it as something that does strict string equality.

Comment: I added the Authorize URI and reran the script, but the new request used a different localhost. So, I added another URI, and again another localhost used to the request. I have a list of 10 URIs now.......

Comment: The issue I believe is after you add the redirect URL in Google API console and press save. You should press ctrl-F5 to speed up the registration of that new URL.

Comment: These OAuth management consoles are aggressively difficult to use. There's no reason for it, either. It's just messy, lazy UX. I've been setting up OAuth logins for years, and I always struggle with this last step: "tell Facebook/Twitter/Google what the damn address of my web site is, in spite of their terrible OAuth management console".

Comment: So how can I change the Google console to not want to go outside the root of my app in the callback? I have no idea why it wants `xxxx.edu/authcallback/indexasync` and not `xxxx.edu/APPNAME/authcallback/indexasync` <- it should be this one

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that my authorized uri contained `https`, and I was redirecting to `http`

Comment: Also: please don't make the mistake of trying to use a Service Account (where such redirect URI list is absent) -> because a Service Account will return the cryptic message regarding missing redirect URI).

Comment: For me the problem was to change from https to http scheme in the OAuthClient2 section.

Answer (score 205):

In my case it was `www` and `non-www` URL. Actual site had `www` URL and the **Authorized Redirect URIs** in Google Developer Console had `non-www` URL. Hence, there was mismatch in redirect URI. I solved it by updating `Authorized Redirect URIs` in Google Developer Console to `www` URL.

Other common URI mismatch are:

- Using `http://` in Authorized Redirect URIs and `https://` as actual URL, or vice-versa
- Using trailing slash (`http://example.com/`) in Authorized Redirect URIs and not using trailing slash (`http://example.com`) as actual URL, or vice-versa

Here are the step-by-step screenshots of Google Developer Console so that it would be helpful for those who are getting it difficult to locate the developer console page to update redirect URIs.

> 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com
> 2. Select your Project

[image: Select your Project]

> 3. Click on the menu icon

[image: Click on the menu icon]

> 4. Click on `API Manager` menu

[image: Select API Manager menu]

> 5. Click on `Credentials` menu. And under `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs`, you will find your client name. In my case, it is `Web Client 1`. Click on it and a popup will appear where you can edit **Authorized Javascript Origin** and **Authorized redirect URIs**.

[image: Select Credentials menu]

**Note**: The Authorized URI includes all localhost links by default, and any live version needs to include the full path, not just the domain, e.g. https://example.com/path/to/oauth/url

Here is a Google article on [creating project and client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project).

Comment: I kept Authorized JavaScript origins empty and Authorized redirect URIs

 as http://127.0.0.1/google_account/authentication and it worked from me.

Comment: Help me Please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270512/google-log-in-issue-in-published-website-but-fine-in-dev-mode?noredirect=1#comment69744948_41270512

Comment: For those struggling with this, if you created your app via some other google page (such as the Drive API page), you might not see these options. I had to delete and recreate the Client ID from WITHIN the API Manager console.

Comment: In order to see the JavaScript Origins and redirect URIs, I needed to set the Application Type to "Web application":

Comment: i didnt find this option. maybe the UI changed?

Comment: I was doing this for a Firebase-created app, and had to disregard creating a new Client ID, instead using the one named "Web client (auto created by Google Service)"

Comment: In my case, the problem was a slash :|

Comment: Follow this solution: This will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567446/14591547

Answer (score 139):

If you're using **Google+ javascript button**, then you have to use `postmessage` instead of the actual URI. It took me almost the whole day to figure this out since Google's docs do not clearly state it for some reason.

Comment: Since this question is the top hit when googling the error message, here are some additional pointers.  As Mike says, use "postmessage" for your redirect URI.  You need to specify this in 2 places (if you are using the web-app-server-flow).  One is in the g-signin button on the javascript.  The other is in the signet authorization client in your server code.

Comment: great answer. I was posting with javascript and needed to set 'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'postmessage' in the google API config.php file.

Comment: I have no strength to find out what "postmessage" as a redirect uri (wtf?) means, but you saved me! thanks!

Comment: postmessage sounds nice, but it results in the useless `Error: invalid_request` `origin parameter is required!`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976227/3338098 allowed me to set the redirect to whatever I needed

Comment: @MikeKeskinov How do I use a `postmessage` instead of an URI?

Comment: Just put the word "postmessage" where an URI should be.

Comment: After spending few hours trying to solve this problem, your answer help me a lot! The Google documentation is not very clear. In server side, if you use the Google API Client library, you should use this code : `$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');` instead of `$client->setRedirectUri('http://your.url...');`

Comment: Can you help me with my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307612/google-analytics-oauth2-error-redirect-uri-mismatch

Comment: Wow.... @Guicara solution worked for me after hours of beating my head against a wall.

Comment: In GO:
```&oauth2.Config{
  ClientID:   ...,
  ClientSecret: ...,
  Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
  RedirectURL:  "postmessage",
  Scopes:      ...,
 }
```

Comment: I was struggling to solve this issue with django-rest-social-auth and angular frontend. Its working when I passed 'postmessage' as redirect_uri. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Important addition: I discovered that on **cross-client server auth flow** you should use "postmessage" when you received your `serverAuthCode` from Web SDK, BUT set `redirect_uri` **empty** when you received `serverAuthCode` from **Android** or **iOS** SDK.

Comment: Wow, I was skeptical when first seeing this answer because there's no mention of it anywhere I could find in the docs. After changing the POST parameter to exchange the "authorization_code" for an access token to `redirect_uri: 'postmessage'`, it does work.

Comment: works like magic

Comment: omg, huge thanks to you guys! I wasted over a day on this. Just out of interest, where is that part regarding 'postmessage' mentioned in the docs?

Comment: This is also the right answer if you are using Google Identity Services to get an authorization code via the popup method. See Jeff Ward's answer for more info.

Answer (score 118):

In any flow where you retrieved an **authorization code** on the client side, such as the **[`GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess()` API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthgrantofflineaccessoptions)**, and now you want to pass the code to your server, redeem it, and store the access and refresh tokens, then you have to use the literal string `postmessage` instead of the redirect_uri.

For example, building on the snippet in the [Ruby doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/web-app):

```rb
client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load('client_secrets.json')
auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
auth_client.update!(
  :scope => 'profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
  :redirect_uri => 'postmessage' # <---- HERE
)

# Inject user's auth_code here:
auth_client.code = "4/lRCuOXzLMIzqrG4XU9RmWw8k1n3jvUgsI790Hk1s3FI"
tokens = auth_client.fetch_access_token!
# { "access_token"=>..., "expires_in"=>3587, "id_token"=>..., "refresh_token"=>..., "token_type"=>"Bearer"}
```

The only Google documentation to even mention `postmessage` is this [old Google+ sign-in doc](https://developers.google.com/+/sign-in-faq). Here's a screenshot and [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317184124/https://developers.google.com/+/sign-in-faq) since G+ is closing and this link will likely go away:

[image: Legacy Google+ API DOC]

It is absolutely unforgivable that the [doc page for Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) doesn't mention this. *#FacePalm*

Comment: @mariobgr Yeah, other answers here mention `postmessage`, but I wanted to give the specific circumstances (e.g. `grantOfflineAccess`) of when this crazy undocumented hack was necessary for me. :P I didn't want it to be true either. :) Cost me hours of headache.

Comment: Another `postmessage` thing that burned me for a few hours this morning: After parsing through Google's own Python client code, I finally came across this: "postmessage: string, this is generally set to 'postmessage' to match the redirect_uri that the client specified"

Also, in their documentation: "The default redirect_uri is the current URL stripped of query parameters and hash fragment."

Which means that if your `redirect_uri` is not the current url, then you'll need to explicitly specify it in `gapi.auth2.init()`, and on the server side, you'll use `postmessage`.

Comment: Jeff, you are awesome! I just spent hours trying to debug Google's Auth API and this was one of the issues. Insane "solution" that is not documented anywhere. In fact, their own docs give wrong answers here. Fantastic! (Also, What the actual %2F Google?)

Comment: `postmessage` solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 68):

For my web application i corrected my mistake by writing

```
instead of : http://localhost:11472/authorize/
type :      http://localhost/authorize/
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it helps.  I was stuck on this because the GitHub OAuth2 API does *not* require you to remove the port number.

Comment: That worked for me, too. I was following this course: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on and getting 'redirect uri error'. After I've changed https://localhost:44334/signin-google to https://localhost/signin-google it worked. Thanks a lot for useful tip.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was testing with this https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples and "The redirect URI in the request" appeared to be from a different port every time that i ran it. This helped me so much. It would have taken hours to figure out what was happening!

Comment: Amazing, this worked perfectly for my case! I had to add http://127.0.0.1/authorize/ , as it wasn't resolving to the localhost DNS

Answer (score 57):

1.you would see an error like this

[image]

2.then  you should click on **request details**
[image]

after this , you have to copy that url and add this on https://console.cloud.google.com/

3. go to https://console.cloud.google.com/

[image]
[image]

4. click on Menu -> API & Services -> Credentials

[image]

5. you would see a dashboard like this ,click on edit OAuth Client
   [image]
6. now in `Authorized Javascript Origins` and `Authorized redirect URLS`
   add the url that has shown error called `redirect_uri_mismatch` i.e here it is
   http://algorithammer.herokuapp.com , so i have added that in both the places in
   `Authorized Javascript Origins` and `Authorized redirect URLS`
7. click on save and wait for 5 min and then try to login again

Comment: This works, seems no need to wait 5 minutes, <= 2 minutes is fine in my case.

Answer (score 41):

Make sure to check the protocol "http://" or "https://" as google checks protocol as well.
Better to add both URL in the list.

Comment: No, it's better to just make sure you're using https.

Answer (score 17):

This seems quite strange and annoying that no "one" solution is there. 
for me http://localhost:8000 did not worked out but http://localhost:8000/ worked out.

Comment: this is because the `redirect_uri` must be an EXACT MATCH on the developers console and in your application.

Comment: I had no ending "/" neither in the developers console and the application. Both were exact matches, and it did not work. I had to add an ending "/" for the script to work.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks. Don't know why this is needed though.

Answer (score 14):

This answer is same as [this Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990247/9814131), and [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121098/9814131), both sets `redirect_uri` to `postmessage` on client side. I want to add more about the server side, and also the special circumstance applying to this configuration.

## Tech Stack

### Backend

- **Python 3.6**
- **Django 1.11**
- **Django REST Framework 3.9**: server as API, not rendering template, not doing much elsewhere.
- [**Django REST Framework JWT**](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) 1.11
- [**Django REST Social Auth**](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) < 2.1

### Frontend

- **React**: 16.8.3, `create-react-app` version 2.1.5
- [**react-google-login**](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login): 5.0.2

## The "Code" Flow (Specifically for Google OAuth2)

Summary: React --> request social auth "code" --> request jwt token to acquire "login" status in terms of your own backend server/database.

1. Frontend (React) uses a "Google sign in button" with `responseType="code"` to get an authorization code. (it's not token, not access token!)

   - The google sign in button is from `react-google-login` mentioned above.
   - Click on the button will bring up a popup window for user to select account. After user select one and the window closes, you'll get the code from the button's callback function.
2. Frontend send this to backend server's JWT endpoint.

   - POST request, with **`{ "provider": "google-oauth2", "code": "your retrieved code here", "redirect_uri": "postmessage" }`**
3. For my Django server I use Django REST Framework JWT + Django REST Social Auth. Django receives the code from frontend, verify it with Google's service (done for you). Once verified, it'll send the JWT (the token) back to frontend. Frontend can now harvest the token and store it somewhere.

   - **All of `REST_SOCIAL_OAUTH_ABSOLUTE_REDIRECT_URI`, `REST_SOCIAL_DOMAIN_FROM_ORIGIN` and `REST_SOCIAL_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI` in Django's `settings.py` are unnecessary**. (They are constants used by Django REST Social Auth) In short, **you don't have to setup anything related to redirect url in Django**. The `"redirect_uri": "postmessage"` in React frontend suffice. This makes sense because the social auth work you have to do on your side is all Ajax-style POST request in frontend, not submitting any form whatsoever, so actually no redirection occur by default. That's why the redirect url becomes useless if you're using the code + JWT flow, and the server-side redirect url setting is not taking any effect.
4. The Django REST Social Auth handles account creation. This means it'll check the google account email/last first name, and see if it match any account in database. If not, it'll create one for you, using the exact email & first last name. But, the username will be something like `youremailprefix717e248c5b924d60` if your email is `youremailprefix@example.com`. It appends some random string to make a unique username. This is the default behavior, I believe you can customize it and feel free to dig into their documentation.
5. The frontend stores that token and when it has to perform CRUD to the backend server, especially create/delete/update, if you attach the token in your `Authorization` header and send request to backend, Django backend will now recognize that as a login, i.e. authenticated user. Of course, if your token expire, you have to refresh it by making another request.

Oh my goodness, I've spent more than 6 hours and finally got this right! I believe this is the 1st time I saw this `postmessage` thing. Anyone working on a `Django + DRF + JWT + Social Auth + React` combination will definitely crash into this. I can't believe none of the article out there mentions this except answers here. But I really hope this post can save you tons of time if you're using the Django + React stack.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, my credential Application type is "Other". So I can't find `Authorized redirect URIs` in the credentials page. It seems appears in Application type:"Web application". But you can click the `Download JSON` button to get the `client_secret.json` file.
[image]

Open the json file, and you can find the parameter like this: `"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]`. I choose to use http://localhost and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 10):

Checklist:

- `http` or `https`?
- `&` or `&amp;`?
- trailing slash(`/`) or open  ?
- `(CMD/CTRL)+F`, search for the exact match in the credential page. If
  not found then search for the missing one.
- Wait until google refreshes it. May happen in each half an hour if you
  are changing frequently or it may stay in the pool. For my case it was almost half an hour to take effect.

Answer (score 9):

When you register your app at https://code.google.com/apis/console and 
make a Client ID, you get a chance to specify one or more redirect 
URIs.  The value of the `redirect_uri` parameter on your auth URI has to 
match one of them exactly.

Comment: And it is with very field that has problems for deep Angular based links as google doesn't agree [http://landed1.github.io/videos.html#/oauth2callback]is a valid URL

Answer (score 8):

for me it was because in the 'Authorized redirect URIs' list I've incorrectly put `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/` instead of `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` (without `/` at the end).

Answer (score 8):

It has been answered thoroughly but recently (like, a month ago) Google stopped accepting my URI and it would not worked. I know for a fact it did before because there is a user registered with it.

Anyways, the problem was the regular 400: redirect_uri_mismatch but the only difference was that it was changing from https:// to http://, and Google will not allow you to register http:// redirect URI as they are production publishing status (as opposed to localhost).

The problem was in my callback (I use Passport for auth) and I only did

```
callbackURL: "/register/google/redirect"
```

Read docs and they used a full URL, so I changed it to

```
callbackURL: "https://" + process.env.MY_URL+ "/register/google/redirect"
```

Added https localhost to my accepted URI so I could test locally, and it started working again.

TL;DR use the full URL so you know where you're redirecting

Answer (score 6):

2015 July 15 - the signin that was working last week with this script on login

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

stopped working and started causing Error 400  with `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch`

and in the DETAILS section: `redirect_uri=storagerelay://...`

i solved it by changing to:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp"></script>
```

Comment: Encountering the same Error 400, but changing the script did not work inside of my Cordova WebView.

Comment: @NickSpacek please check if the missing double quotes were responsible.

Answer (score 6):

The redirect url is case sensitive.

In my case I added both:
http://localhost:5023/AuthCallback/IndexAsync
http://localhost:5023/authcallback/indexasync

Comment: And be careful with the character "/" at the end of the URL. Sometimes is needed, others times not.

Comment: so we can keep localhost as request_uri even for live websites?

Answer (score 6):

If you use this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow then you should use "postmessage".

In GO this fixed the problem:

```
confg = &oauth2.Config{
        RedirectURL:  "postmessage",
        ClientID:   ...,
        ClientSecret: ...,
        Scopes:      ...,
        Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
}
```

Answer (score 6):

beware of the extra `/` at the end of the url 
`http://localhost:8000` is different from `http://localhost:8000/`

Answer (score 6):

Just make sure that you are entering URL and not just a domain.
So instead of:
**domain.com**
it should be
**domain.com/somePathWhereYouHadleYourRedirect**

Comment: Yes, this was my issue with NextAuth. When using the default GoogleProvider, it uses `https://example.com/api/auth/callback/google`, which you actually have to specify in your dashboard.

Answer (score 6):

I also get This error Error-400: redirect_uri_mismatch

This is not a <kbd>server</kbd> or <kbd>Client side</kbd> error but you have to only change by checking that you haven't to added **/ (forward slash)** at the end like this

redirecting URL list ❌:

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
```

Do this only ✅:

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
```

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I had http://localhost:3000/ in the address bar and had http://127.0.0.1:3000/ in the console.developers.google.com

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Rails users (from the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) docs):

> ## Fixing Protocol Mismatch for redirect_uri in Rails
>
> Just set the full_host in OmniAuth based on the Rails.env.
>
> # config/initializers/omniauth.rb
>
> OmniAuth.config.full_host = Rails.env.production? ? 'https://domain.com' : 'http://localhost:3000'

REMEMBER: Do not include the trailing "/"

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me. below did

change authorised Redirect urls to - https://localhost:44377/signin-google

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: if we use localhost it will work for published website too. I mean if in the API console I add the localhost request URI. How will it work when the web site gets live? Or for live sites we need to put another set of actual URI in API Console?

Answer (score 3):

Anyone struggling to find where to set redirect urls in the new console: APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs -> Click the link to find all your redirect urls

Answer (score 3):

I have frontend app and backend api.

From my backend server I was testing by hitting google api and was facing this error. During my whole time I was wondering of why should I need to give `redirect_uri` as this is just the backend, for frontend it makes sense.

What I was doing was giving different `redirect_uri` (though valid) from server (assuming this is just placeholder, it just has only to be registered to google) but my frontend url that created token code was different. So when I was passing this code in my server side testing(for which redirect-uri was different), I was facing this error.

So don't do this mistake. Make sure your frontend `redirect_uri` is same as your server's as google use it to validate the authenticity.

Comment: I have a React front end and a Flask back end and this answer fixed my issue. thanks

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:
If using the **Google_Client** library do not forget to update the JSON file on your server after updating the redirect URI's.

Comment: how to update that?

Comment: @RohanDevaki download and replace the JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

Important addition: I discovered that on **cross-client server auth flow** you should use "postmessage" when you received your `serverAuthCode` from Web SDK and set `redirect_uri` **empty** when you received `serverAuthCode` from **Android** or **iOS** SDK.

Comment: DUDE I was stuck on this for 15 hours and you blessed my life! Thank you!!

For others, on my python backend, when verifying token code, I passed redirect_uri ="" and it worked. I also followed https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access properly and now it all works (I'm using the deprecated library though but it works for now and it seems to do the same thing as normal one)

Answer (score 2):

Let me complete @Bazyl's answer: in the message I received, they mentioned the URI 
`"http://localhost:8080/"`
(which of course, seems an internal google configuration). I changed the authorized URI for that one, 
`"http://localhost:8080/"` , and the message didn't appear anymore... And the video got uploaded... The APIS documentation is VERY lame... Every time I have something working with google apis, I simply feel "lucky", but there's a lack of good documentation about it.... :(  Yes, I got it working, but I don't yet understand neither why it failed, nor why it worked... There was only ONE place to confirm the URI in the web, and it got copied in the client_secrets.json... I don't get if there's a THIRD place where one should write the same URI... I find nor only the documentation but also the GUI design of Google's api quite lame...

Comment: Both URI's you posted look identical.  What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to create a new client ID under APIs & Services -> Credentials -> Create credentials -> OAuth -> Other

Then I downloaded and used the client_secret.json with my command line program that is uploading to my youtube account. I was trying to use a Web App OAuth client ID which was giving me the redirect URI error in browser.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for this issue will only come from chrome and chrome handles WWW and non www differently depending on how you entered your URL in the browsers and it searches from google and directly shows the results, so  the redirection URL sent  is different in a different case

[image]

Add all the possible combinations you can find the exact url sent from fiddler , the 400 error pop up will not give you the exact http and www infromation

Answer (score 2):

In my case the redirect-uri is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/google/callback`
and I keep requesting through `http://localhost:5000/auth/google` 
Make sure if you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do these checks:

1. Bundle ID in console and in your application. I prefer set Bundle ID of application like this "org.peredovik.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}"
2. Check if you added URL types at tab Info just type your Bundle ID in Identifier and URL Schemes, role set to Editor
3. In console at cloud.google.com "APIs & auth" -> "Consent screen" fill form about your application. "Product name" is required field.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to check the Client ID type for web applications/installed applications.

installed applications: http://localhost [Redirect URIs]
In this case localhost simply works

web applications: You need valid domain name [Redirect URIs:]

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go back to your Developer Console and go to APIs & Auth > Consent Screen and fill that out. Specifically, the product name.

Comment: Also, don't use a product name that is also used in another project.  Make sure it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

I had two request URIs in the Console,

```
http://xxxxx/client/api/spreadsheet/authredirect
```

and

```
http://localhost.
```

I tried all the top responses to this question and confirmed that none of them were my problem.

I removed localhost from the Console, updated my `client_secret.json` in my project, and the mismatch error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with google sign in.

I had correctly entered my callbacks in google Credential panel at google developer console
here was my redirect urls :

```
https://www.example.com/signin-google

https://www.example.com/signin-google/

https://www.example.com/oauth2callback

https://www.example.com/oauth2callback/
```

Everything seems fine right? But it still didn't work until I added one more **magical Url** I added **signin-google** URL (which is default google callback) **without** **www** and problem solved.

**Take it into account (depending on your domain) you may or may not need to add both with and without www URLs**

Answer (score 1):

Below are the reasons of Error: redirect_uri_mismatch issue occurs :

1. Redirect URL field blank at your google project.
2. Redirect URL does not match with your site
3. Important! It will work only with working domain like example.com, book.com etc (Not work with local host or AWS LB URL)

**Recommended to use domain URL**

Comment: What should be done is google generates wrong redirect_uri param all the time? It is generated as localhost:XXXXX with a random port number, ignoring redirect uri I set up creating client.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to input the right redirect url at the point of creating the ID. I found that updating the redirect url once the ID has been created via an 'Edit' just doesn't get the job done. What also worked for me is duplicating the entire 'vendor' folder and copying it to the same location where the 'oauth' file is (just until you successfully generate the token and then you can delete the duplicate 'vendor' folder). This is because trying to point to the vendor folder via '../vendor/autoload' didn't work for me.

So, delete your existing troublesome Client OAuth ID and try this approach, it will work.

Comment: That didn't work for me, Google still wants me to provide it with a URI that is outside of the root folder of my website: 
`redirect_uri: https://XXXXX.edu/AuthCallback/IndexAsync`
it should be this
`https://XXXXX.edu/FOLDER/AuthCallback/IndexAsync`

Answer (score 1):

To make it work on localhost and if using for web-server, do provide

```
Authorized JavaScript origins (Client ID for web appication)
e.g. http://localhost:4200
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using Meteor and Ngrok, while trying to login with Google.
I put the Ngrok URL in the Google Developer Console as redirect URLs, and went to the Ngrok URL page. The thing was that I didn't use Meteor's `ROOT_URL` when executing the app, so any redirect would go to `localhost:3000` insted of the Ngrok URL. 
Just fixed it by adding the Ngrok URL as `ROOT_URL` on Meteor's configuration or by exporting it before executing the app on the terminal like: `export ROOT_URL=https://my_ngrok_url`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue to authorize in Reactjs app on my local machine with port 3000.
I have added `lvh.me` in authorized domains and `http://lvh.me:3000` for authorized origin and authorized redirect URL as shown in following images respectively.

**Note: You can add multiple sites for verified domains. i-e for your local machine, staging or other environments**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using passport js and you are deploying your app in heroku you need to add this setting proxy: true in passport strategy

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
    {
        clientID: keys.googleClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
    })
```

or check your authorized url

must be https://yourwebsite/auth/google/callback

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added

```
https://websitename.com/sociallogin/social/callback/?hauth.done=Google
```

in `Authorized redirect URIs` section and it worked for me

Comment: where did you add?

Comment: 'Authorized redirect URIs' field

Answer (score 0):

In my case resetting the secret ('reset secret'-button) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **OAuth consent screen** on your Google https://console.cloud.google.com/

then **click** on the **PUBLISH APP**.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you've deployed your app on the Cloud and using a Load Balancer. It's utterly confusing in this case because you'll keep seeing that you've specified the correct callback URI but Google keeps saying your URI is not an exact match. The solution is to enable Sticky Sessions on your Load Balancer. If you are using Elastic Beanstalk in AWS, this is done by simply adding a .ebextensions/load-balancer.config file in your build directory, with the following content:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    StickinessEnabled: 'true'
    StickinessLBCookieDuration: '43200'
```

If you're using a Load Balancer and you've double checked your URI multiple times. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Amplify make sure you check your `amplify-config.js` or whatever you are passing into `Amplify.configure(CONFIG);`.

Make sure that these are set properly:

```
"redirectSignIn": "https://develop.de58tqweqi5gdus.amplifyapp.com/",
"redirectSignOut": "https://develop.de58tqweqi5gdus.amplifyapp.com/",
```