# Google OAuth 2 auth - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch even after registered uri

Tags: php, curl, google-api, access-token, google-oauth

I'm trying to exchange authorization_code for access_token with Google OAuth2

```
$client_id = urlencode(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client_sec = GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;  
$redirect_uri = urlencode("http://example.com/path/auth.php");
$code = 'Authorization_code_received';
$post="code=$code&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_sec&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&grant_type=authorization_code";
$ch=curl_init();
$url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$json=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($json);
```

I get this 
`"error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"` 
My problem is exactly same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) but I also registered my redirecturi in google api console long time and its active.

anyone has idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

go to `https://code.google.com/apis/console` and check redirect URIs in `Client ID for web applications` section....check if that redirect URI set in your code `$redirect_uri = urlencode("http://example.com/path/auth.php");` is same as on google api console....

may be thats the reason...

Comment: I checked it they both match, and still having this issue. Thanks for your help though.