# Google OAuth 2.0 returns invalid redirect_uri_mismatch when getting access_token

Tags: access-token, google-oauth

I am trying to exchange an OAuth one-time use code that I got from my client-side app into a access token and refresh token on my server. The response that I get is:

```
{
    "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}
```

My POST request is:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={My Code}&
client_id={My Client ID}&
client_secret={My Client Secret}&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I have checked my Client ID and Client Secret against those in the API Console and they match.

I get the one-time use code on my client with the following Java code:

```
static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"});
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", SERVER_CLIENT_ID, TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(c, email, scope);
```

I have a redirect_uri in my API Console, but since I am trying to use cross-client authorization (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth)), I deliberately left it out of the POST request as is required:

> When it exchanges the code for tokens, it should not include the “redirect_uri” argument in the POST.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that "should not include the 'redirect_uri' argument in the POST" does not mean to completely omit the redirect_uri field. It instead means that the redirect_uri field should have an empty value.

My new, working POST is:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={My Code}&
client_id={My Client ID}&
client_secret={My Client Secret}&
redirect_uri=''&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: What library are you using on the server side? My guess is that the library sort of requires redirect_uri to be set, if you omit it then it sends some default. When you explicitly set an empty value then send that through, but empty values are treated exactly the same as no parameter at all at the OAuth 2 endpoints.

Comment: This was the last piece of the puzzle that I was missing. Thanks @quantumwannabe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184995/775359 - answer was helpful:

```
var post_data = {
  code : code,
  client_id : google_client_id,
  client_secret : google_client_secret,
  redirect_uri : 'postmessage',
  grant_type : grant_type,
};
```

Setting redirect_uri to **postmessage** solved my issue with redirect_uri  mismatch.

EDIT: Another answer referencing postmessage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990268/775359