# Google API - Redirect URI mismatch error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am implementing google+ signin on my web application.
I tried it by referencing from this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow).

My google+ sign in button is as follows:

```
<div id="signinButton">
    <span class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-clientid=[MY_CLIENT_ID] 
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback"> </span>
</div>
```

I have copied js given on above link on my webpage.

After getting authorization code, I am forwarding this to my servlet, below is my implementation for forming url to get tokenResponse.
Note: I am not using google libraries for server side implementations.

Here is my url forming code:

```
String httpsURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

     String query = "code="+code; 
     query += "&";
     query += "client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID]&";
     query += "client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&";
     query += "redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/oauth2callback&";
     query += "grant_type=authorization_code";

     try{
     URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
     HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
     con.setRequestMethod("POST");
     con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
     con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
     con.setDoOutput(true); 
     con.setDoInput(true); 
     con.connect();
     OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
     wr.write(query);
     wr.flush();
     InputStream is;
     if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {
         is = con.getInputStream();
     } else {
         is = con.getErrorStream();
     }
     //URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
     //conn.setDoOutput(true);
     // Get the response
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     String line;
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
     {
         System.out.println("-----" + line);
     }
     wr.close();
     rd.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

On developer console, my redirect-uri is same as given in above code sample.

After executing all this, every time I get this : "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch".

There are so many questions asked on this, but they didn't solved my problem.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the Google+ Sign-In, which does **not** use your Redirect URI. Instead, it uses a magic URI of `postmessage`.

You don't need to add `postmessage` to the developer console ([the directions](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret) (step 1, item 7c) usually say to clear this field completely), but you **do** need to use it when you're exchanging the code for tokens (see the sample code in [step 8](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_8_initialize_the_google_api_client_library_and_start_the_google_service)).

So your code above should read something more like

```
 String query = "code="+code; 
 query += "&";
 query += "client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID]&";
 query += "client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&";
 query += "redirect_uri=postmessage&";
 query += "grant_type=authorization_code";
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.. I wasted hours on this. It is working now. :)

Comment: Glad to help. If it worked for you, please consider accepting this as an answer in StackOverflow by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. You can also upvote it by clicking on the up arrow.