# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch ; questions related to previous posts

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-plus

Well, I am also encountering the same error  which has been discussed online many times, however, I have some questions regarding some of the previous discussions which could help me in troubleshooting my problem:

Q1: The very first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) says that "The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be registered in the APIs console". So, I have `http://myportal.com` defined for both `REDIRECT URIS` and `JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` as shown in the image below:

[image]

Does it means that I have registered the redirect URI properly?

Q2 Another answer to a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954086/google-oauth2-authorizing-oauth-token-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) talks about `installed applications`. What does installed applications means here?

Q3. In the error, I keep on getting `The redirect URI in the request: http://myportal.com/session/oauth2callback.cfm did not match a registered redirect URI` I don't know from where `outh2callback.cfm` is getting added over there as I have already removed `out2callback` thing from the end of `REDIRECT URIS` section as clear from the image above.

Answer (score 0):

1) The redirect URI must match exactly between the parameter and the application configuration while the JS origin only requires that the domains match. E.g. if you are using `http://example.com/callback/google.cmf` as your redirect URI, then `http://example.com/callback/google.cmf` should be in the application settings.

2) Installed applications are software that users install on their computer. E.g. iTunes or Outlook.

3) `http://myportal.com/session/oauth2callback.cfm` is the redirect URI parameter value you use in the authentication flow that entire URI needs to be configured in the Google APIs console as your redirect URI.