# Chrome Extension with G+ Signin - redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that the user can login to with their Google account. I have based it on this sample code: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript and it gets as far as `gapi.auth2.init` but then 400 errors with `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch`. The client ID is registered fine.

The API call fails because the redirect_uri is wrong, but what URI do I set for an extension? The API call is made as so:

```
  gapi.auth2.init({
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    client_id: '1234_valid_id_1234',
    cookie_policy: 'none',
    redirect_uri: 'xxx',
    scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
  }).then(
```

'xxx' as the uri is just an example, I've tried multitude of options in here, to no avail.

The extension will load a dialogue as if it's going to begin the auth process but then craps out with the 400 error. I don't understand what URI an extension should be providing as a callback here, surely this isn't applicable?

The client ID etc is fine - if I run the sample JS code on just a standard localhost website it all works fine, it's only when trying to use it in an extension that it breaks, because of the lack of callback URI.

Comment: You have to put `postmessage` instead of actual URI. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954086/google-oauth2-authorizing-oauth-token-error-redirect-uri-mismatch/17976227#17976227

Comment: this doesn't make any difference. whatever i change redirect_uri to, i always see the error returned with the redirect_uri set to "storagerelay://chrome-extension/appidinhere?id=auth963268". i don't seem able to override this and i have no idea what sotragerelay is or where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference
gapi.auth2.init doesn't take redirect_uri param.

Only function that takes redirect_uri is grantOfflineAccess. redirect_uri = "postmessage" should always work.

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
  client_id: '1234_valid_id_1234',
  cookie_policy: 'none',
  scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
});

// on user click
auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(
  function(resp) {
    var auth_code = resp.code;
  });
```

Comment: what i don't get is that the error shows the redirect uri thus: redirect_uri=storagerelay://chrome-extension/12345?id=auth82093 even if i specify postmessage in the object called in auth2.init - whatever i change that value to it still shows this redirect_uri in the failure?!

Comment: This is a bug on Google side. I've reported it and I'll let you know when it will be fixed. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: thank you. please let me know where you raise a ticket.

Comment: It's internal Google ticket, no way to share:/

Comment: It turns out that it's more complicated than a simple bug fix. Can you use redirect_uri which is registered in https://console.developers.google.com/ (Select project > APIs & auth > Credentials > Redirect URIs) ? If that doesn't work could you send me a error message that occurs?