# Getting started with Google Actions SDK

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I'm an absolute beginner trying to get started with Google Actions development using Actions SDK for Google Assistant, following the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/sdk/getting-started#getting-started). I'm getting stuck at step 3 under "Deploy fulfillment and preview the action package" on that page. After I issue the command in that step, I get a URL which I'm supposed to paste into a browser and get an OAuth-2.0 authorization code. But when I paste the URL into the browser, I get an error like below. I looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954086/google-oauth2-authorizing-oauth-token-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch), and tried most of the solutions proposed there with no success. Can anyone help please?

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme: u rn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
>
> access_type=offline
>
> client_id=....apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> redirect_uri=u rn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
>
> response_type=code
>
> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant
>
> state=state

Comment: Found Any Solution ? I am facing the same here..

Comment: It's resolved, I just tried it agian and it worked fine..

Comment: It's resolved. Apparently, when I copied and pasted the URL into the browser, it contained some spaces. I removed the spaces and it works. Ugh, I want my 8hrs back!