# Google+ login redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: ios, api, google-plus

I want to edit my bundle id that was registered in Google APIs Console for Google+ login.

Answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) tells me how to do that but I don't see `Client id` and `secret` under `API Access` as he is saying. May be because Google APIs Console has changed.

Does anyone know how to edit currently registered bundle id for Google+ integration in Google APIs Console?

**Edit :**  I could not see client id and secret because that was somehow got deleted. I created a new one. Replaced client id with existing. But still same error.

Comment: use correct bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a new client id. Make sure that Google+ API is enabled in google console.

Answer (score 8):

In My case I added wrong bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Follow following steps to get secret  and client id

1) Open API Access in google API console. Then click on create a client ID.

like...

[image]

2) Fill Following form.

[image]

3) you will get client id

[image]

Comment: I created a new one. But still same error. I created same way as you suggest.

Comment: in which application you are trying iphone or android

Comment: This solved my problem when trying to use same client ID in two applications forgetting that when you create your credentials you have to enter Bundle ID. Once I created new one with current bundle id everything worked as expected.