# Google oauth2 redirect uri mismatch

Tags: google-oauth

I setup my credentials for using google oauth2 as a method of signing up. Works fine locally, but when I try and signup on the staging site I get a "redirect_uri_mismatch" error. Even after I copy and paste the url its complaining about into the redirect uris section. I am at my wits end and have almost thrown my laptop across the room several times. Help would be appreciated since google support is non-existent.

Comment: what is the uri? maybe google has no access to it? maybe something like localhost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Double check on the google console.  On the cloud console under APIs & Auth -> Credentials, click the Create New Client ID red button.  Make one for a web application.  You may have to come back and edit it in order to get the redirect/callback uri set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping the `port`?

http://example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

I had the same issue using http://localhost:9000 ...

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works and no `redirect_uri` was provided when initiating the Google client, try using `postmessage` in the `redirect_uri` field.

Answer (score -1):

I code rails, and I have to change the Oauth2 redirect uri in the google console, as well as my own code:

In development:

OAUTH2_REDIRECT: http://local.domain:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

In production:

OAUTH2_REDIRECT: http://example.com:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

I've learned The Hard Way to make sure these config vars are right *everywhere*.