# redirect_uri_mismatch - What is wrong with the address I'm using?

Tags: google-oauth, caldav, roundcube

When I try to access my Google calendar (via Roundcube webmail, using google_oauth2 plugin), I get this exact error:

Error:  redirect_uri_mismatch error. The redirect URI in the request: 
http://mail.domain.com:1066/?_task=settings&_action=google_redirect&_enable=cb did not match a registered redirect URI

My webmail is hosted at this address: http://mail.domain.com:1111/RCmail/

My google project settings are as follows:

Authorized JavaScript origins

http://mail.domain.com:1111

Authorized redirect URI

http://mail.domain.com:1111/RCmail/?_task=settings&_action=google_redirect&_enable=cb
https://mail.domain.com:1111/RCmail/

NOTE:  directing to mail.domain.com:1111 (without the RCmail path) just redirects it to my xampp page which isn't what I want

Comment: check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch
, it might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Because the redirect_uri in the request doesn't match any one you register in Google sonsole.
check it again, they are different:

> http://mail.domain.com:1066/?_task=settings&_action=google_redirect&_enable=cb
>
> http://mail.domain.com:1111/RCmail/?_task=settings&_action=google_redirect&_enable=cb