# OAuth Google Plus sign in: 400. That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I had tried to implement OAuth authorization via GooglePlus sign in.
I did everything mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp) and especially [this](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2)(thanks Matt Johnson a lot). But it didn't work. I got this every time:

**The redirect URI in the request: http://somesite.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback did not match a registered redirect URI.**

After several attempts to change settings, I found the solution (see answer below).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) There was another problem

Comment: Excelent, DalmTo. You don't know for sure if this post is duplicate - but you have already marked it as -1. Thanks. Now I see "how stack works"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution becomes quite easy and surprising.
The right Redirect URIs is:

***http://somesite.com/account/externallogincallback***

instead of

*http://somesite.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback*

It turned up that this parameter is case sensitive.

Comment: Didn't know that. And what for the checkbox below "Ask a question form" than?