# getting redirect uri mismatch error in google plus despite having no uri mismatch

Tags: redirect, oauth, google-api, google-plus

Please consider the following two websites that I am pinging as shown in the image below:

[image]

I have a google plus login icon where a user can click on it and can sign in using his/her google account.

My website where all the login code is residing is say for example `xyztesting.com` as shown in the image. And all the code related to `xyztesting.com` resides on the box `10.11.10.12` which has a domain name `abctesting.com`.

So, when i ping `abctesting.com`, I get **Packets Sent and Received = 4** as shown in the image.

However, when I ping `xyztesting.com` , I get `Request timed out` as shown in the image below.

Does anyone knows whether this could be the reason behind why I am getting `Redirect URI Mismatch error 400` error whenever a user tries to log in using google plus ?

I have ensured that the `REDIRECt URI` in the request matches the `Registered Redirect URIs` which is the most common message displayed when some one encounters this error and this is the most common fix suggested online everywhere.

I have referred to lot of previous related posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) where they talks about making sure that the request URI's should match the registered URI on google developer console.

I have got a feeling that since there is not a dedicated box/server for my website `xyztesting.com`, google is thowing such error. Please let me know if anyone has experienced such type of error with the situation I have described above?

Comment: i believe that redirect URI needs to be the file you want to redirect to. for example xyztesting.com\index.php

Comment: Can you provide examples for how your sign-in button is configured and what valid URLs are set in the console.

Comment: Pinging and IPs should have no impact on the redirect URI. What matters is that the redirect URI (including domain and path) you tell the button matches exactly the redirect URI you have configured in the API console.

Comment: @abraham Hmm, then what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: You don't provide enough detail. Please link to an example we can view and include a screenshot of your apps redirect URI configuration from the API console.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the `redirect uri` should be set to "`postmessage`" not the actual *uri*.
The documentation is not so clear on that setting.
-Dragonfire