# OAuth for LinkedIn error: "A confirm Email Address is Required to proceed"

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

When tried with someone elses account:

[Is there a naming standard for REDIRECT URIS OAuth 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790351/is-there-a-naming-standard-for-redirect-uris-oauth-2-0)

http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/connect-to-linkedin-using-oauth-in.html

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: i also facing this issue. any know about this ?

Comment: this still happens for me

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this problem. I was having this issue connecting my profile with 3rd party apps.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Verify your email
2. If you have verified your email, add a secondary email, and verify that one.

My issue was #2. I had a verified primary email, but once I put in another one, it worked.

You can also try removing the 3rd party app access from your account and allowing access again.