# Google OAuth 2.0 "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: oauth, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I spend already one day, crashed one glass and I am really angry about it, I do not understand what google want from me, and what is wrong.

I've enabled Google+ Api in developers console
[image: google_ api enabled]
, 
created new OAuth Client ID
[image: client id]

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'code=4%2FPp1GWqC6PIr3wNYrZ5kK4T9oitxBoo0fBqBrVNQfE-g.ElKDUjQ7E28SoiIBeO6P2m-0RPaolgI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyprivatedomain.local.com%2Foauth2callback&client_id=%mycliet_id%&client_secret=%mysecret%');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
```

created all like in instructions here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow, gplus button appear on page, and it successfully request access for authorized user. but when I made step 8 **Step 8: Initialize the Google API client library and start the Google+ service**
my request every time get response **"error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"**

I know, that this error appear when you do not registered redirect_uri in Google Console, or when you make a type mistake in it, but I registered it, and also just for testing tried to setup different urls (changed domain names, changed protocols from https to https), but it never working! I have no idea what else I can check, please advice at least something.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client?

Comment: @Hans Z yes, as part of my symfony2 application

Comment: `Friendly Note:` select "Web Application" instead of "Other" when creating credentials, I selected "Other" and ran into problems, it worked in local but did not work on live domain

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The docs say in Step 1. https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret that there must be no redirect URIs configured, only "Authorized JavaScript origins". In the authorization request and the token exchange, the `redirect_uri` parameter value should be set to `postmessage`.

Edit: 
Prior art on this: [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: thank you very much! it was not obviously that redirect url in client config should be "postmessage", it working now! instruction said that postmessage should be value of attribute data-redirecturi, but never client_config, that's a mess

Comment: The other thing to note is that there is a delay between setting the value in the credentials screen, and when they take effect and the login process works.  For me it was a couple of minutes each time I changed something.

Comment: After spending few hours trying to solve this problem, your answer help me a lot! The Google documentation is not very clear. In server side, if you use the Google API Client library, you should use this code : `$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');` instead of `$client->setRedirectUri('http://your.url...');`

Comment: In my case it was www. My URL is without www while in Credentials I entered URL with www. Also take care of http and https. Better enter all the options.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it helped me.

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver!! Took me 2 days to find it. I was retrieving a serverAuthCode via Android / JS (cordova and https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus to be exact) and sending it to PHP to exchange for an access token. "postmessage" is the required redirect_uri when cuing straight CURL in PHP.

Comment: FFS google absolutely on documentation 
https://www.google.co.jp/search?num=100&ei=TOj8WtanB4Lo0gSL7ZeoDA&q=google+%2Bpostmessage+inurl%3Agoogle&oq=google+%2Bpostmessage+inurl%3Agoogle&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2518.5186.0.5330.15.14.1.0.0.0.115.1129.10j3.13.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.eT20SlJcMA8

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this problem myself. In my case, my credentials were set up for an **installed application**, *NOT* a web application. It seems that `Installed application`s cannot be configured with `redirect URL`s. I created a new credential as a `web application`, and this gave me the option to set a series of `redirect url`s.

Following the advice of this and other answers, I made sure the URL's matched (copy-paste) and this functioned correctly for me. I also did this in an Incognito Window.

The result was my browser being forwarded to the URL I put in the `redirect_url` parameter with a special query string parameter `code` populated with the code to use for the next step.

Answer (score 0):

If seeing this when using the [Google IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/), if you attempt to visit your URL in a browser, you'll get the message:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, [your_url]/_gcp_gatekeeper/authenticate, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/?project=[your_project_id]

if you visit the the URL it gives you (or indirectly via [the console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) >> click edit on the correct "OAuth 2.0 client ID"), in the "Authorised redirect URIs" section, ensure you have the `[your_url]/_gcp_gatekeeper/authenticate` URL set.

The `_gcp_gatekeeper/authenticate` part is definitely required.

Google return the 400 error because of the mismatch in redirect URI.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issue :

1. The setRedirectUri was set a http and server was running on https and
   setAccessType to online ( for production )

> ```
> $client = new Google_Client();
> $client->setAuthConfig(_DIR_ . '/../public/client_secrets.json');
> $client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
> $client->setAccessType('online');
> $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
> ```

2. Inside my auth config file ( client_secrets.json ) . I changed the
   redirect_uris, client_id, project_id, and client_secret

> ```
> {
> "web":{
>   "client_id":"GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
>     "project_id":"PROJECT_ID",
>     "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
>     "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
>     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
>     "client_secret":"CLIENT_SECRET",
>     "redirect_uris":["https://DOMAIN_NAME.com/social-auth/google/callback",
>               "http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback.php"],
>   "javascript_origins":["https://localhost","http://localhost:8000"]
>     }
> }
> ```