# Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error for cross-client single-sign on

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, google-oauth

We are trying to implement Google's OAuth 2.0 cross-client sign-on functionality so that our server keeps the tokens and associates them with users, as shown in the diagram for the flow here: [Google OAuth 2.0 Server-Side Flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)

I am able to successfully retrieve a one-time access code on the client app. I then send that code to the server via a post to "http://example.com/oauth2callback/code="

It gets to the server just fine. The server then attempts a POST to Google that looks like this:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={My Code}&
client_id={My Client ID}&
client_secret={My Client Secret}&
redirect_uri="http://example.com/oauth2callback"&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

However, each time the server is returning "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch."

We have tried everything. We double-checked the redirect_uri matches EXACTLY in the Google console and the client ID and client secret are correct. It still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured this out eventually, but I wanted to post this here so that others can find it. It turns out that you should NOT specify a redirect URI if you are exchanging a one-time access code for an access token via communicating with Google's servers from your own server. Instead, it should look like this:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code={My Code}&
client_id={My Client ID}&
client_secret={My Client Secret}&
redirect_uri=''&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Answer (score 2):

In the "server-side" flow your `redirect_uri` should be set to `postmessage`. Unfortunately that is not clearly documented by Google. See also [Google OAuth 2.0 "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321570/google-oauth-2-0-error-redirect-uri-mismatch/28322123#28322123) and related questions/answers.