# Using Python to do basic Google Drive operations without web server authentication

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to create a Python script that can do some really basic things (add/remove files in a shared google drive)
The script will be running on remote PCs so anything involving web authentication is off the table

I read online that using a service account was the way to go, so I did the following:

- Created a project
- Enabled the Google Drive API for the project
- Created a service account for the project (left "Grant this service account access to project", couldn't figure out what, if anything, I should put here)
- Created a key for the service account, downloaded it and tried to use it the following way:

  ```
   service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
   SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly&#39',
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

   creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info, scopes=SCOPES)

   service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

   results = service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
   items = results.get('files', [])
  ```

Which results in an exception after my "results" line executes:

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.',
> {'id_token': '[longtoken'})

I saw something that hinted I needed to use the "OAuth 2.0 Playground" where I tick off "Use your own Oauth credentials", specify the ClientID and ClientSecret and authorize the Google Drive APIs but when I try to do that I Just get "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch" (and I'm not sure if resolving this will actually get me anywhere)

Is there a viable way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: A quick search showed many similar questions, have you tried this?https://stackoverflow.com/a/28322123/8363401

Comment: In your question, you say `Created a key for the service account, downloaded it and tried to use it the following way:`. But the script is trying to retrieve the file list instead of the download of file. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry, retrieving a file list was just a proof-of-concept to show that I could do _something_ with service

Comment: For installed applications, please read the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and the sub section [Installed Aplications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed)

Comment: @AdamVengroff were you successful in achieving what you wanted?

Comment: No I gave up and went with an alternate route. It looks like a service account can do what  I want to do but I wasn't able to find a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You're missing these steps:

1. Setting up Oauth consent
2. Create OAuth Client ID Credentials for a Desktop App using the OAuth Consent
3. Tunnel a remote port from your server to your local Machine

Service account is possible but it is also possible to authenticate on a remote machine -[see here](https://suzyahyah.github.io/misc/2022/05/10/remote-googledrive.html)