# Google OAuth 2 authorization - only work on localhost

Tags: oauth-2.0

At localhost, my website can use account Google to log in.

When i upload website to server I get this error :

> An error occurred: "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

That is because the redirect URI that you send in the authorization request (in the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter) is not registered for your client in the Google API Console. See: [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)