# redirect_uri_mismatch error of google API while trying to login using c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-oauth, google-signin

I need to login throw google in my page. I got my clientID and set the redirect_uri path in Google Console but when I am trying to login it is giving me the following error. I am integrating this on my asp.net page.

> Error:
>       400. That’s an error.
>       Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>       Application: odiyaDoctor
>       You can email the developer of this application at: odiyadoctor@gmail.com
>       The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx did not match a registered redirect URI.

My requirement is when user will login by google on first page(`UserLogin.aspx`) and after successful login the next page(`i.e.immediateHelp.aspx`) will come. I am explaining my all code and google credentials below.

**UserLogin.aspx:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-google" onclick="googleLogin();"  >Login with Google <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<script>
    var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
    var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
    var CLIENTID = '*************************g96b1elfa8.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var REDIRECT = 'http://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx';
    var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
    var TYPE = 'token';
    var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
    var acToken;
    var tokenType;
    var expiresIn;
    var user;
    var loggedIn = false;
    function googleLogin() {
        var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
        var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            try {
                console.log(win.document.URL);
                if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    var url = win.document.URL;
                    acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
                    tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                    expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                    win.close();
                    validateToken(acToken);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('its error', e);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    function validateToken(token) {
        $.ajax({
            url: VALIDURL + token,
            data: null,
            success: function (responseText) {
                getUserInfo();
                loggedIn = true;
                window.location.href = "immediateHelp.aspx";
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }
    function getUserInfo() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
            data: null,
            success: function (resp) {
                user = resp;
                console.log('user info',user);
                $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }
    function gup(url, name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\#&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(url);
        if (results == null)
            return "";
        else
            return results[1];
    }
</script>
```

In the above page the bellow error is coming in catch section.

> at http://localhost:3440/UserLogin.aspx:92:32
>       UserLogin.aspx:103 its error DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3440" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>           at Error (native)
>
> clientID set in google.

Client ID for web application

```
Client ID   
***************************************1ctsjaeg96b1elfa8.apps.googleusercontent.com
Client secret   
*********oGbT13hv3S
Redirect URIs   
https://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx
JavaScript origins  
https://localhost
```

Here i need when user will logged in successfully,it will redirect to the `immediateHelp.aspx` page and in this page user can do the logout.Please help me to resolve these errors.

Comment: In google developer console you need to add  http://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx as a redirect uri

Comment: @ Dalm To : I have already added .check above post.

Comment: "The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx did not match a registered redirect URI."   Google doesn't lie you don't have it.

Comment: Also it looks like all your code is JavaScript should it really be tagged .net and asp.net ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

```
`"http://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx" != "https://localhost/immediateHelp.aspx"
```

The URL must be character perfect

Comment: whats about the second error.How this will be resolved.

Comment: second error? This is StackOverflow. One question per thread.