# Uploading to youtube with Youtube API without User's Interaction

Tags: youtube-api

I have an app on the server, I need to upload some videos to one (only 1) youtube account, but without user/browser/client's interaction (I don't want an OpenID/OAuth to be shown), how can I achieve this?

I've googled, but all I ever found is always requires user interaction.

[image: requires UI]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to OAuth into one account (your own) to enable uploads without requiring user input.  If so, you can create OAuth credentials on the Google API Console [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) (which I believe is the page in your screenshot) by choosing **Create credentials** > **OAuth client ID** > **Web application** > **Create**.

Once you have the client ID and client secret, you can use the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278384/youtube-api-without-user-oauth-process/37311692#37311692) to generate an access and refresh token, and use these in your server code when making the API upload request.

On a side note, if you are collecting video submissions from users, YouTube recommends you have users upload to their own accounts, for a variety of reasons.  See this [blog post](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2012_02_01_archive.html) for details; in particular:

> One crucial consideration is which account the videos will be uploaded
>   to on YouTube. It’s tempting to design a system in which all videos
>   are uploaded to a single “master” YouTube account, but this is always
>   the wrong approach. While using a master account means that each
>   uploader doesn’t need to register for their own YouTube account, a
>   high rate of uploads into a single YouTube account is a good way to
>   run afoul of the YouTube API’s quota system. Additionally, each
>   uploader to YouTube agrees to YouTube’s Terms of Service, which says
>   that they have the right to upload that content, and that the content
>   does not violate our Community Guidelines. By taking responsibility
>   for other users’ content, you are essentially putting your own account
>   and YouTube standing at risk.