# Google Analytics API: How to solve OAuth2 Missing Scope Parameter Error?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to get this example to work: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-php#enable

The error I'm getting is "Error: invalid_request, Missing required parameter:scope"

In order to install the google api resources, I used composer with this command:

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

This installed the "vendor" folder in my root site folder. My index.php and oauth2callback.php files are located in the "public_html" folder.

Here's what I have in my index.php:

```
<?php
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // Set the access token on the client.
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    // Create an authorized analytics service object.
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
    // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();

                // Return the first view (profile) ID.
                return $items[0]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}

function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
    // for the last seven days.
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '7daysAgo',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
        print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
    } else {
        print "<p>No results found.</p>";
    }
}
```

Then here's what I have in my oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I have read up similar errors and saw someone posting that just by adding:

```
passport.authenticate('google', {scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'});
```

it'll work, but I don't know where to add this, nor do I know if it will solve my problem.

Also, I don't know if it's necessary to know, but the client_secrets.json file is in the same folder as the index.php file; (public_html) folder.

By the way, in my Google API manager, I have my Authorized redirect URIs set to only "http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback.php" which was what the first reference I linked in this question said to do. I don't think this should be a problem, but just wanted to get the entirety of my question here.

Can anyone help me understand what to do from here?

I'll attach a screenshot of what I'm seeing as the error.

[image: scope error message]

Comment: By calling the composer install google file as google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC, should I be doing a different version than 2.0.0? Just a thought..

Comment: "the client_secrets.json file is in the same folder as the index.php file; (public_html) folder." This is not recommended, you should put this file in a more secure location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this (index.php);

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
```

To this;

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
```

Also, you're missing `addscope` on your callback, change this (oauth2callback.php);

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php')
```

To this;

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php')
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
```

You can find more information here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started#setup

***Side note;***

> Also, I don't know if it's necessary to know, but the
>   client_secrets.json file is in the same folder as the index.php file;
>   (public_html) folder.

**This is not recommended**, you should put the json file outside of the 'webapps' directory, such as a config folder.

Comment: I just edited to exactly that, yet I still have the same error. Is this a cache issue at all? still missing scope

Comment: Would it possibly have anything to do with an HTACCESS file that I have in my project folder only allowing my IP address?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think you may have been missing it on your call back as well? Let me know

Comment: This worked, although now I'm getting a different error when I try to select my account: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Comment: Glad it worked! Your redirect_uri needs to be registered in the API - Go to the project console and you should see a list of authorised redirect_uri's - Click edit settings and add your uri

Comment: I went there and I have two things listed there: http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback.php/ and http://example.com/oauth2callback.php/ where example, is my domain

Comment: Sorry, not sure on that one - I just knew the answer to your original Q. Hope you manage to sort it, there's a few answers here which may help  you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch

Comment: That's ok, thank you for all your help so far. I'll figure the rest out on my own.

Comment: Do you have the `http://` for your redirect URIs? you may also need to redownload the file after making changes?