# Google Oauth Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: amazon-ec2, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use google Oauth 2 to authenticate with google calendar API for a web server running on AWS EC2.

When I generated the credentials I selected 'OAuth Client ID' and then 'Web Application'. For the Authorised redirect URIs I have entered:

http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
(I've blanked out the IP of my EC2 instance). I have checked this is the correct URL that I want the callback to go to.

The link that is generated in the server logs is of the form:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:47258/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

When I follow the link I get the error
'Error: redirect_uri_mismatch'.

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) and have checked that I am using HTTP and there is no trialing '/'

I suspect that the URL generated should not have 'localhost' in it but I've reset the client_secret.json several times and each time I restart tomcat with the new client secret I still get a link with localhost but just over a different port.

Locally, I had selected Credentials type of 'other' previously and was not given an option for the Authorised redirect URI. I did try this for the EC2 instance but this won't give me the control I want over the redirect URI and sends the redirect over localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google throws `redirect_uri_mismatch` when the uri (including ports) supplied with the request doesn't match the one registered with the application.

Make sure you registered the `Authorised redirect URIs` and `Authorised JavaScript origins` on the web console correctly.

This is a sample configuration that works for me.[image]

Comment: Thanks, issue was port number

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Google contiunues adding localhost:XXXXX as redirect_uri, ignoring redirect uris set for OAuth client. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In case you are seeing this error while making API call from your server to get tokens.

### Short Answer  - What solved my problem

use string `postmessage` in place of actual `redirectUri` that you configured on cloud console.

Here is my initilization of OAuth2 client that worked for me.

```js
// import {Auth, google} from 'googleapis`;

const clientID = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
oauthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientID,clientSecret,'postmessage');
```

#### My Case

On the frontend, I am using react to prompt the user for login with google with the `authentication-code` flow. On success, this returns `code` in the payload that needs to be posted to the google API server to get `token` - `Access Token`, `Refresh Token`, `ID Token` etc.

I am using `googleapis` package on my server. Here is how I am retrieving  user info from google

```js
// import {Auth, google} from 'googleapis`;

const clientID = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
oauthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientID,clientSecret,'postmessage');

/*
    get tokens from google to make api calls on behalf of user.
    @param: code -> code posted to backend from the frontend after the user successfully grant access from consent screen
*/
const handleGoogleAuth = (code: string) => {
    oauthClient.getToken(code, async (err, tokens: Auth.Credentials) {
        if (err) throw new Error()

        // get user information
        const tokenInfo = await oauthClient.verifyIdToken({
          idToken: tokens.id_token
        });
    
        const {email, given_name, family_name, email} = tokenInfo.getPayload();
        // do whatever you want to do with user informaton
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping i was stuck on this from last week.
really helpful

Answer (score -1):

When creating a Oath client ID, DO NOT select web application, Select "Other". This way, the Redirect URI is not required.

Comment: Not a viable solution. If you're going to use Oauth from the browser, you need to use "web application". It just doesn't work with "other".