# Google Login 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, google-signin

I have added google login in my asp.net website. I think I have done all settings properly. I got App ID & App Secret and configured properly. Also I have set redirect URL properly in my google console & website is uploaded in the same URL still it shows following URL.

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: GoogleLogin

What other things needs to be take care?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: @Loofer please read my entire question first then take it as duplicate. I mentioned all the settings I have done correctly including redirect url. What you marked as duplicate in that person has not included redirect url.