# Facebook and Google Redirect URL are not HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

https://www.example.com

I've installed SSL to my `ASP.NET MVC 5 site`, but the problem is the when I clicked Login with Facebook or Google the redirect url is not https

`https://web.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=**http**%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsignin-facebook&scope&state=xxxxxx`

this creates redirect mismatch bec i've registered the https version

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help?

> The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be
>   registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you
>   haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

[Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)