# google-api-nodejs-client throws invalid_request error when exchanging code with tokens

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I've got a simple client app using react-google-login with this settings:

```
<GoogleLogin
        clientId={config.CLIENT_ID}
        scope={config.SCOPES.join(' ')}
        buttonText="Login With Google"
        onSuccess={response => onSignIn('google', response)}
        onFailure={this.failure.bind(this)}
        accessType="offline"
        responseType="code"
      />
```

It retrieves the code successfully and sends it to the backend server which is written with NodeJS.

The server-side code looks like this:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const config = global.config;
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
  clientId: config.google.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: config.google.CLIENT_SECRET,
});

// code omitted for the sake of simplicity

var authCode = req.body.authCode; // the provided code by google

const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(authCode);
return tokens;
```

When I run the code, it throws the error:

```
{ error: 'invalid_request',
        error_description: 'Missing parameter: redirect_uri' } },
  code: '400' }
```

and if I add redirectUrl to Developer Console, client app and server-side app, I'll get `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

I'm kind of stuck here and couldn't find anything useful on the web.

Any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: You must set the same redirect_uri server side in your Google App.

Comment: I did. I got `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

Comment: You get mismatch error because the URL you saved in your app is not the same you are sending in the request. The URLs must be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you @marekful, but I found the solution and shared it below. The problem was not the url at all. I had to use `postmessage` instead of url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Found the solution**

Based on one of the replies (surprisingly, not the answer) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch),

All I needed to do was put `postmessage` instead of the actual URL in my client react-google-login button and in oauth2Client config on the server.

no need for the redirect_uri on Developer Console at all.

```
<GoogleLogin
            clientId={config.CLIENT_ID}
            ****redirectUri="postmessage"****
            scope={config.SCOPES.join(' ')}
            buttonText="Login With Google"
            onSuccess={response => onSignIn('google', response)}
            onFailure={this.failure.bind(this)}
            accessType="offline"
            responseType="code"
          />

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
  clientId: config.google.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: config.google.CLIENT_SECRET,
  ****redirectUri: 'postmessage'****
});
```

Did solve the issue. 5 hours of working, searching and beating my head to the desk. I wonder why there's no clear documentation on Google Developers website. Or maybe there are and I couldn't find them.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot. There is still nothing about 'postmessage' in guides

Comment: You have saved me from going insane!