# Google OAuth2 - Node.js Retrieve authorization code gives 400

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I have a web application with React and Node.js and I am trying to connect to the Google Search Console API.

It requires authorisation so on the front end I am connecting to the correct account and scope and I am getting the OAuth2 `authorizationCode` it look something like this:

`4/0AX4XfWg2MKbTfn41rBjuv1wn4u5VF4G1m5p8q6-_Px-FL991ccJsn-qn6xdUbJqfM73TEw`

I am then sending it to the back end but the `OAuth2` returns `400`

Here is what I got:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

export default async () => {

  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
  );

  google.options({
    auth: oauth2Client
  });

  // It throws 400 on this line
  const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(authorizationCode);
  oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

  const { data } = await google.webmasters.sites.list({});
  console.log(data);
}
```

But I get 400 Bad Request

Comment: a little confused, which line is getting error 400?

Comment: This one `const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(authorizationCode)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, there was two problems the first one was really silly and I forgot to add the object properly to the `new google.auth.OAuth2` instead of

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
})
```

I had written

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URL
);
```

And the second thing was this answer from another person with similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876985/google-api-nodejs-client-throws-invalid-request-error-when-exchanging-code-with)

Where I had to change the `redirectUri` from `https://localhost:3001` to `postmessage` on both the back and fron end... go figure, no where to be found on the [googleapis docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/searchconsole/classes/Resource$Sites.html#list)