# How we can implement google sign-in registration in saleor django framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-signin, saleor

I tried to implement this where I inserted my google client id key and my gmail password, at the fields key and password located at:

*saleor dashboard > configuration > site settings > authorization key > google auth2.0.*

Output I get is:

```
error400
redirect uri mismatch
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding authorization key in Saleor's dashboard, you should enter the Google API Console and add the `http://yourwebsite.com/complete/google-oauth2/` URL in there. Please make sure that's the exact URL your site is redirecting to, as simple changes: eg protocol, or trailing slash will make it not work.