# Why is Google OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch giving a false positive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, google-oauth, puma

I have a rails app running behind nginx, nginx has letsencrypt certificates enabled, but rails is not encrypted. When I try to authenticate with Google OAuth2 I get:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://example.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/something
```

[image]

Then when I visit the link to check my credentials I get:

```
Failed to load

Tracking Number: somenumber
```

[image]

But when I go to to the developers console both URLs the one showing up in the 404 error and the one I have specified in **Authorized redirect URIs** are the same.

Comment: Here are some informations about the same problem, please check peoples experience in comments below, because some mentioning that after one hour service works well and in some periods they had similar issues or so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch

Comment: @Nezir Thanks. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: no you dont need to do that, just if my link is useful to you please vote and please read comments and info on that link and try fixes and suggestions in your problem,  thank you

Comment: @Nezir Got it! Thanks.