# Swagger with Google OAuth 2.0 authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, google-oauth, swagger-2.0

Swagger passes `access_code` by default to headers. Is it possible to pass `id_token`?

I'm documenting my NodeJS REST API with `swagger.yaml` version `2.0`

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to pass an Id_token? and where would you want to pass it to?

Comment: I have all my endpoints authorization based on `Authorization: "Bearer id_token"`.

Comment: I have no idea why that would even work or why you would even do that.  Id_tokens are not bearer tokens access tokens are.  You might want to read up on the difference between open id connect and Oauth2 Sorry i cant help you with your question as your not using standard authorization and authentication practices

Comment: Thanks for that. Just wanted to know if it is possible coz would save me a lot of work.

Comment: Actually you need to request the tokentype "token id_token" which results in a token containing scopes for user info endpoints (additional to the already requested scopes) - this is the thing i am looking for right now and I cant find a way to do it...

Comment: @Ravior _"Actually you need to request the tokentype "token id_token" which results in a token containing scopes for user info endpoints"_ It depends on the identity provider and flow. This question is about [Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) ( `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`) which uses `response_type=code` aka authorization code flow.

Comment: @Ravior (cont.) Whereas `response_type=token id_token` is specific to OpenID Connect. OIDC is currently [not supported](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3517) in Swagger UI, as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784134/113116) to your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible even though it's not a good idea as [mentioned by @DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982278/swagger-with-google-oauth-2-0-authorization#comment100504092_56982278).

You need to add `x-tokenName: id_token` to the Google OAuth security definition in your API definition.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

securityDefinitions:
  google_oauth:
    type: oauth2
    description: Google OAuth
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
    tokenUrl: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
    x-tokenName: id_token   # <-------
    scopes:
      ...
```

**Note:** To use `x-tokenName` in OpenAPI 2.0 definitions you need Swagger UI 3.8.12+; to use it in OpenAPI 3.0 you need Swagger UI 3.25.0+.

Comment: Is there a possibility to set oAuth `redirectUrl`?

Comment: Redirect URL can be changed by using the [`oauth2RedirectUrl`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-oauth2redirecturl) parameter in the `SwaggerUIBundle({ ... })` constructor in your index.html. Make sure to actually host the [oauth2-redirect.html](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/oauth2-redirect.html) page at this custom location, and also [register this redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485644/113116) in Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Swagger or Nswagg use a different token (id_token or access_token) by setting the x-tokenName in the security configuration, such as following:

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
{
    config.PostProcess = document =>
    {
        document.Info.Title = "API OpenBankWeb";
        document.Info.Description = "Uma simples Web API feita em ASP.NET Core consumindo AWS.\nClique nos títulos abaixo para expandir.";
    };
    config.AddSecurity("oauth2", new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        ExtensionData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "x-tokenName", "id_token" }
        },
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = _domain + "/oauth2/authorize",
                TokenUrl = _domain + "/oauth2/token"
            }
        }
    });
```

This can be very handy when using AWS Cognito, since it uses only id token for authentification.