# Swagger UI ignoring x-tokenName extension

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Im using Swashbuckle v5.0.0 in a .net-core 2.1 application to generate my api-documentation.

I've added this security definition:

```
cfg.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
   Name = "oauth2",
   Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
   Scheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
   {
      { "x-tokenName", new OpenApiString("token id_token") }
   },
   Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
   {
      Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
      {
         Scopes = swaggerSettings.Scopes,
         AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(authorizationUrl),
         TokenUrl = new Uri(swaggerSettings.IdentityProviderUrl + "/connect/token"),
      }                                
   },
});
```

This is the api-specification that is getting generated from it (just the important part):

[image: The security part of the generated API-Specification]

It almost works perfectly, as I can even open the following dialog in the swagger ui and also do a full authorization:

[image: Fully working authorize dialog]

But the problem is, even though the x-tokenName value is set to "token id_token" (which is required to receive an access token containing also identity-scopes, as profile and openid), the request send by the swagger-ui, recorded by fiddler, is this (cut to the important part):

```
GET /usermgmt/identityprovider/connect/authorize?response_type=token&[...]
```

On the web I can find threads about that what I'm trying to achieve was supported for a while, then it wasnt and I don't know if it is now - it seems it isnt but I think this feature is important so it should be there.

I need this because I want to request user-groups from the profile-endpoint using access tokens created on the request of the swagger-ui.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `x-tokenName` in Swagger UI. This extension specifies the field of the OAuth 2.0 token endpoint response to be extracted and subsequently used in the `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

By default, the bearer token is extracted from `access_token`:

```
{
  "access_token": "abcde12345",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "id_token": "...."
}

=>

Authorization: Bearer abcde12345
```

If the security scheme definition specifies, for example, `x-tokenName: id_token`, then the value of `id_token` will be used as the bearer token instead:

```
{
  "access_token": "....",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "id_token": "xyz987"
}

=>

Authorization: Bearer xyz987
```

More info about `x-tokenName`: [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4084) and [here](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/apis/vendor-extensions#api-docs-x-tokenname).

> I want to achieve that the authorization link swagger ui generates and sends the user to the identity-provider contains "response_type=token id_token&[...]"

`id_token` is used in Open ID Connect (OIDC) flows, which is an extension of OAuth 2.0. Swagger UI currently [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3517) OIDC.

When OIDC is supported in Swagger UI, you'll also need to change your security scheme definition from `type: oauth2` to [`type: openIdConnect`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/):

```json
{
  ...
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "openId": {
        "type": "openIdConnect",
        "openIdConnectUrl": "https://path/to/.well-known/openid-configuration"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks so far. I want to achieve that the authorization link swagger ui generates and sends the user to the identity-provider contains "response_type=token id_token&[...]" because I found out so far that this is required to get an access-token with identity-scopes included. Do you know a way to do achieve this using the swagger-documentation?

Comment: So you use Open ID Connect, not vanilla OAuth 2.0. Swagger UI does not support OIDC yet - please see the updated answer.

Comment: For anybody looking for an example for `response_type=token id_token`, I created an example that uses wrapActions plugins at my github repository: 
https://github.com/inouiw/SwaggerUIJsonWebToken