# Google sign in works fine in local host but not in custom domain

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-web

I am trying to sign in with google in `flutter web`. The code is working perfectly fine in android and IOS (and in web only in `localhost`).
I am trying to add my domain URL in javascript origin which starts from 'http://' and it gives me the following error.

```
Invalid Origin: You are using a sensitive scope. URI must use https:// as the scheme
```

**I hope anybody knows how to solve. Bundle of Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Similar question to: [Cannot add http url to Authorized redirect URIs in gcloud's OAuth 2.0 client IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014378/cannot-add-http-url-to-authorized-redirect-uris-in-gclouds-oauth-2-0-client-ids)