# issue with google login with php

Tags: php, google-console-developer

I am making google login for my website. I have also set my google console settings in my google developer console. and use this code for google login.

but it shows me an error: 400 redirect_uri_mismatch while I have already set my redirect_url

and my question is different from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top) because as we can see in that question redirect_uri is not declared but I have already declared it.

I am showing my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="*********CLIENT-ID********">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();" style="display: none;">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

When I click on Google signup button it redirects on URL

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%abc.com%3Fid%3Dauth535373&response_type=permission%20id_token&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&client_id=*******&ss_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.com&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2

and shows me Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.

I don't know why this happens.

can anybody help me in this.

Comment: put `redirect_uri` same as defined in google app. Even `/` is in the end of the URL. Check you `redirect_uri` carefully

Comment: @Gulshan I have already put / at the end of URL. my redirect_uri is correct it is my domain name but still it is not working.

Comment: did you find any solution on google or google API documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to find the solution in the google API documentation but I am failed to found it that's why I have put a question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Gulshan no it is not duplicate because of this question asked in 2017 but in latest settings are different than that