# Does OAuth permit localhost for debugging?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-developers-console

I'm working on Yii2, using google/apiclient.
I keep getting "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"

- I've set "http://localhost" as authorized redirects
- Tried with "https://localhost"
- Tried with "https://localhost/"
- Waited more than 1hr for changes to take effect

Nothing seems to work, any insights?

My code is nothing special:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;

    $gClient = new Google_Client();
    $pathToSecret = Yii::getAlias('@app/auth/gCalendar_ClientSecret.json');
    $gClient->setAuthConfig($pathToSecret);
    $gClient->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS_READONLY);
    $gClient->setLoginHint('my_mail@not.relevant');
    if ($session->has('oauth_access_token')) {
        $gClient->setAccessToken($session->get('oauth_calendar_access_token'));
        //do something else
    } else {
        $redirectUri = Url::toRoute('/calendar/oauth-response', 'http');
        $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
        return $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    }
```

Based on the error, the request seems fine:

> The redirect URI in the request, 
>       http://localhost/ascoSL/public_html/sl/index.php?r=calendar%2Foauth- 
>       response, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update 
>       the authorized redirect URIs, visit: 
>       https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/XXXXX

[image: See a capture of my google config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your API endpoint in the google API console:

> Please note that the exact (absolute) route you're using needs to be registered

This has already been answered here and im sure you can find your answer here too: [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: I've done that, I'm showing the config in a picture link. Here it is again for you good sir: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnaqA.png)

Comment: Your redirect url you are sending to the server, doesnt look like it will match what you have in the google console: These lines in your Else statement: $redirectUri = Url::toRoute('/calendar/oauth-response', 'http');
        $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);

Comment: Also add http://localhost:8080, and also make sure your server IS actaully running on port 8080

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly you dont need to anwser a question with a link to the duplicate you can just flag it as duplicate if you dont have permissions to flag duplicates just leave it as a comment and someone with the permissions to create the flag will.

Comment: @dalmTo thanks for that, really helpful advice and ill use it in the future when doing triage. Though; as it turns out Edo had read that article and it hadn't helped, so Im happy i did end up answering and helping him through his issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so turns out the EXACT absolute route has to be registered, I assumed sub-directories would be allowed.
Once the full URI was registered, redirect worked fine.
Thanks SweetChillyPhilly for the link.

Comment: Hey bro, sorry but you don't add your own answer which is an exact copy of my answer. You upvote my answer then I would go ahead and consolidate the comments into the answer itself.

Comment: Yeah, i was writing this during your answer, didn´t notice. Cheers