# I need to upload file in Google Drive using g-suite. Getting "Authorization Error"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I need to upload file in Google Drive using g-suite. I am getting a "**Authorization Error**" error like this:

> The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:62990/authorize/,
> does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the
> authorized redirect URIs, visit:
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/832895456388-gi5bqd65lnfk116es7lp3coes2o724s4.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=832895456388

This is detail of my Keys:

[image: Details]

And here is code:

```
   public ActionResult UploadFiles()
        {
            GSuiteCredentials gSuiteCredentials = new GSuiteCredentials();
            string serverPath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Gsuite/");
            string UserPath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Gsuite/67/client_secret_352975997152-cs82i5rbhe50b7n2m0bk2gut8dlm9sq4.apps.googleusercontent.com.json");
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = gSuiteCredentials.GetCredentials(serverPath, UserPath, "781"),
            });
            string uname = Request["uploadername"];
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                string fname;
                // Checking for Internet Explorer      
                if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                {string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                    fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];}
                else{fname = file.FileName;}
                string fname1 = fname;
                fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
                gSuiteCredentials.UploadAdvance(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"+ fname1)), service);
            }
            return Json("Hi, " + uname + ". Your files uploaded successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**API's keys**

[image]

Comment: You do realise you posted part of your credentials in that screenshot?

Comment: You *already* posted the full ClientID when you posted that URL. You already posted parts of the secret in the original screenshot, now you posted the rest

Comment: i ll delete this key after solve this isses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217889/discussion-between-faizan-hazma-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: NO.
i already  see this .