# How to use Google Sign In Java front end and back end

Tags: java, google-signin, google-authentication

In my application, all I want to do is to get the user's Gmail. I don't use any google services. I want to add Google Sign In for Java front end and validate the user in Java backend.

I am following [openid-connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect) document.

By opening the following link in the browser, I can get the code.

**(GET) Request:**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?
response_type=code&
scope=openid&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/&
client_id=113291176157....
```

**/auth endpoint gets the following:**

```
{
  code: '4/0AfDhmrjDTOo7zOrXxm98E...',
  scope: 'openid',
  authuser: '0',
  prompt: 'none'
}
```

Now to get user details,

**(POST) Request:**

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

{
  "code": "4/0AfDhmrjDTOo7zOrXxm98E...",
  "client_id": "113291176157-aibhsqjf655ve...",
  "client_secret": "lLjenLdeaJnd...",
  "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000/auth",
  "grant_type": "authorization_code"
}
```

**But I get the following response:**

```
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have added the redirect URL to credentials:

[image: I have added the redirect url]

Right now, I'm hoping to open a browser window from Java front end for the user to login to Google. I will receive the `code` value, and it will get `id_token` and validate the user.

I have seen some javascript examples, where they get the `id_token` directly.

So I have multiple questions,

- Why do I need to get the `code` first and request `id_token` later?
- Why am I getting `redirect_uri_mismatch` error?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch/11485644#11485644) answer by any chance. I hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization code exchange request looks like below,

URL: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

The request should be `POST` and data should be sent as `urlencoded` data, not in the request body.

More information [about code exchange](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3)