# Getting Authorization Error in Laravel while implementing Google ads

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api, redirect-uri-mismatch

I am implementing google-ads in my laravel website and i am using this package https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-google-ads
Now, when i am trying to run this command to get refresh token (php artisan googleads:token:generate) i am getting error from google

> **Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**

i think its related to google OAuth, i already setup the credentials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)