# google app script linkedin API: The redirect_uri does not match the registered value

Tags: google-apps-script, linkedin-api

I'm using this Apps Script to access LinkedIn API:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/LinkedIn.gs

After run, getting this log:

```
Execution log
10:04:16 AM Notice  Execution started
10:04:16 AM Info    Open the following URL and re-run the script: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=77syustdz6miq0&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F1T6ofd9Gy-ijGyoDNdqyHwElg-RS11QkEI-LAlKJqnBq6Me12_XMdyS76%2Fusercallback&state=ADEpC8w1sPzE9TNTsnV1uyJxVBG8VsR6NYqrUxO8xy-5KK19jEj0vKQd8OhDFGlRpVZEgvkDKNa8TI7qWbpGUXUvwT6pjTE9CXycFRR1v8in-aiIQMMAobS7JPCNb3uB0pGmv8LpqVUKhUug1hmDT9sRb3-ofWhXI5GsYco901OWd5c9AiA0tsDD5SIBviPsDIUOdfMkEBNteSoa2tLJ7H38F_TGIcGlaw-kFvhy939bFw3M5Kfy9pI-d_ZjH61Kz1xXpI_KS3-j2Ee7ziUSiHn8PU89bc0W8lOTggL7i3J_xreb0deSETveB5EovSyX1mQjZMr-YAuI&scope=r_network
10:04:16 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

I have added different redirect URL's in settings (as decoded redirect_uri from the log without the scope)  but nothing works:
[image]

What should "Authorized redirect URLs for your app" be here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same redirect_url that you set up in the project's consent screen. They have to match. It should match the one from: `OAuth2.getRedirectUri()` which is fetched from your credentials registered with Google.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485644/4243927

---

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2