# CodeIgniter 4 - error "404 (File Not Found)"

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-4

I'm integrating the [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) API for uploading files from an HTML form to Google Drive. It works fine when I implement the code (Ajax and jQuery) in CorePHP, but it doesn't work in CodeIgniter 4. Is the issue due to the URL?

The web browser's console shows an error:

> GET http://localhost:8080/upload.html?code=4/0AX4XfWgb3ql4RL2FfY7RdaL7jgyDOYT3CztsruXIbiLNdziDJKZ_UWFNK3qNzEgdcZrMFQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive 404 (Not Found)

File *index.html* (for log in to the Google account):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Git Login App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
       <button id="login">
           Upload Files to Drive
       </button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File *main.js* (redirects to *upload.html* for uploading files to Google Drive):

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Client id of the project
    var clientId = "";

    // redirect_uri of the project
    var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/upload.html";

    // Scope of the project
    var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

    // The URL to which the user is redirected to
    var url = "";

    // This is event click listener for the button
    $("#login").click(function() {

        // This is the method which will be invoked it takes four parameters

        signIn(clientId, redirect_uri, scope, url);
    });

    function signIn(clientId, redirect_uri, scope, url) {

        // The actual URL to which the user is redirected to
        url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri +
        "&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=" + scope +
        "&access_type=offline";T

        // This line makes the user redirected to the URL
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

File *upload.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Git Login App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="upload.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
     <input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
     <button id="upload">Upload</button>
     <div id="progress-wrp">
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        <div class="status">0%</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="result">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File *upload.js*:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get('code');
    const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/upload.html" // Replace with your redirect_uri;
    const client_secret = ""; // Replace with your client secret
    const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    var access_token = "";
    var client_id = "" // Replace it with your client id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        data: {code: code,
               redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
               client_secret: client_secret,
               client_id: client_id,
               scope: scope,
               grant_type: "authorization_code"},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(resultData) {
                   localStorage.setItem("accessToken", resultData.access_token);
                   localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", resultData.refreshToken);
                   localStorage.setItem("expires_in", resultData.expires_in);
                   window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/GitLoginApp/" + "upload.html");
               }
    });

    function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
        return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
    }

    var Upload = function (file) {
        this.file = file;
    };

    Upload.prototype.getType = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("type", this.file.type);
        return this.file.type;
    };

    Upload.prototype.getSize = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("size", this.file.size);
        return this.file.size;
    };

    Upload.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.file.name;
    };

    Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {
        var that = this;
        var formData = new FormData();

        // Add assoc key values. This will be posts values
        formData.append("file", this.file, this.getName());
        formData.append("upload_file", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
            },
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files",
            data:{
                uploadType: "media"
            },
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', that.progressHandling, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    };

    Upload.prototype.progressHandling = function (event) {
        var percent = 0;
        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
        var total = event.total;
        var progress_bar_id = "#progress-wrp";
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
        }
        // Update progressbars classes so it fits your code
        $(progress_bar_id + " .progress-bar").css("width", +percent + "%");
        $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent + "%");
    };

    $("#upload").on("click", function (e) {
        var file = $("#files")[0].files[0];
        var upload = new Upload(file);

        // Maybe check size or type here with upload.getSize() and upload.getType()

        // Execute upload
        upload.doUpload();
    });

});
```

<sub>I'm new to CodeIgniter 4.</sub>

Comment: change your `redirect_url` in  all of your JavaScript to this: `http://localhost:8080/upload`

Comment: i change my routes to: $routes->get('/upload.html?', 'Home::upload'); and it works finally. Thanks for your too!

Comment: [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: Why is there a space in `" .progress-bar"`?

Comment: Why is there a "T" after the semicolon near "`&access_type=offline"`"? Why is there a "+"  in `+percent`?

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413343/why-were-the-original-poster-and-my-comments-deleted).

Comment: What is "CorePHP"? Do you mean core PHP (not a rhetorical question)? As in vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

if you think the php version and .htaccess settings are correct.. try setting autoroute in the **Config/route.php** file Follow the instructions in the link below
https://caramengetahui.com/artikel/read/cara-mengatasi-file-not-found-cant-find-a-route-for-get

Answer (score -1):

You typically receive a *404 Not Found* response if the server was unable to find the requested resource.

[HTTP 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

> The HTTP 404, 404 not found, 404, 404 error, page not found or file
> not found error message is a hypertext transfer protocol (HTTP)
> standard response code, in computer network communications, to
> indicate that the browser was able to communicate with a given server,
> but the server could not find what was requested.

In your particular case, the `redirect_uri` was pointing to `GET /upload.html` which wasn't clearly defined in your routes file (*app\Config\Routes.php*).

#### Solution

[Define the route in your routes file](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#using-http-verbs-in-routes). I.e:

`$routes->get("upload.html", "Home::upload");`

Where the first parameter represents the *[URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)* and the second parameter represents the responding ***Controller***::***method***.

You can grab query parameters in your *controller method* by using:

```php
// Sample route: http://localhost:8080/upload.html?code=4/0AX4XfWgb3ql4RL2FfY7RdaL7jgyDOYT3CztsruXIbiLNdziDJKZ_UWFNK3qNzEgdcZrMFQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

$params = $this->request->getGet();

/*
* Output.

[
  "code" => "4/0AX4XfWgb3ql4RL2FfY7RdaL7jgyDOYT3CztsruXIbiLNdziDJKZ_UWFNK3qNzEgdcZrMFQ",
 "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
]
*/
```