# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]

Getting this error suddenly, no changes to the webapp, we have links to upload pictures to portal and when we click on the link it gives this error message

Comment: Something has changed. The **redirect URI** is different than the one(s) specified in the Google Cloud Console for the client. Edit your question and show what is configured for the client and what URL your code/html page is specifying in the endpoint call.

Comment: The app in the app engine has a banner which access google drive to get the pictures, when clicked on that google drive icon we get above error, saw that google drive API is enabled and also has the credentials associated with it

Comment: Have you tried steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982485/14663497)?