# Google OAuth code flow, can't exchange code for token with error "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, sdk

I'm implementing social login on my website.
I was able to implement the "One tap" flow, but I need to have an alternative to handle the "cooldown" which prevents the popup from appearing, if the user blocked it or closed it.
So I followed the "Authorization" flow on Google documentation.
Until yesterday morning everything was working fine and I succesfully exchanged the code with a token by calling

`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

or

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

sending secret and everything.
In a first instance I used Postman, then I made a sample code in a Spring project, before preparing the final code in another Spring project.

The first run in the final project I started getting a `400` error, with the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error key.

And then I was never able to do the exchange anymore, I get the same error from Postman as well.

The config is correct (It never changed from when it was working).

How can I solve this??

Here's some code

**FRONTEND**

```js
 this.client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
                client_id: this.clientId,
                scope: "openid profile email",
                ux_mode: "popup",
                redirect_uri: this.redirectUri,
                callback: (response) => {
                    debugger;
                    this.submitFakeForm({
                        clientId: this.clientId,
                        code: response.code
                    });
                }
            });
this.client.requestCode();
```

**POSTMAN PARAMS**

this.redirectUri is identical to the one passed here and set up on Google credentials

[image]

**FOR THE MOST SKEPTICAL, THE AUTHORIZED REDIRECTS :)**

They're repeated in couples, because one is for local development, one is for the integration environment.
And of course the production config is on another credential.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the redirect uri is the same,  because you cant set up a redirect uri in google cloud console with url parms.   Please show me what you have configured in google cloud console.

Comment: If you say so you know nothing about the OAuth protocol. Don't worry I just solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in the docs is this, but I came across [this answer here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121098/16995009) and it's basically suggesting not to pass the real `redirect_uri`, but to use a fixed string `postmessage`.

I want to point up again that I was using the real `redirect_uri` yesterday and it worked.
I will do some tests again in the future and update here if something changes.

For now **just know that using `postmessage` fixed the issue for me**

also I will be using `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` as endpoint, since it's the one mentioned in the (awful) docs, although `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` works just as well.

[image]