# redirect_uri is always localhost when json and console have it as a proper domain of localhost

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console, google-client, google-client-login

I went through [11485271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) but not avail.

I see

[image]

Even though I removed localhost. (And when I gave localhost it was at port 8000 and not 8080)

```
"redirect_uris":["https://local.mysite.com"]
```

https://local.mysite.com is my MAMP PRO setup.

When I goto [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocal.mysite.com&scope={scope}](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocal.mysite.com&scope=%7Bscope%7D) in the browser it works, its just that its not working when I do `python3 script.py`.

So how do I fix this ?