# Google Identity Platform Auth with Tenant fails

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

We are using GCP Identity Platform for Auth. The FE project is using @angular/fire@7.5.1 and Angular v14.

So the login works fine using [SigninWithPopup](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/google#signing_in_users_with_the).

Thing is, our IP users have tenants associated with them and I would like to signing using the tenant information as well. The tenant information comes from a support database, which identifies what is the tenant ID on IP for that user.

So, I went there and added the tenant information before calling the `signInWithPopup`:

```
async signInWithGoogle(tenant: DataModel.Tenant) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  auth.tenantId = tenant.tenantId; <-- this is the difference 
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  return signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
}
```

When I add that tenantId and start the login process, instead of a pop-up asking which of my Google Accounts I want to use, I get one saying: **Access blocked: This app's request is invalid. Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**

If I comment the tenant line, it works fine again.

While the pop-up is open, there is a `error details` that I can click which opens that says:
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.

Thing is, the URL in there is already defined on the Client API Credentials for the OAuth we are using, and the fact that it works when the tenant is not informed, makes me wonder if that is really where the problem lies.

Anyone knows what else should I be looking to make that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: Actually, it does. I had read through that in the past. The problem here was that my devops gave me the wrong Client Id information and thus I had the configurations done properly but for a client that was not being used by sign-in. Once I had that figured out, things started to work as they should.