# Google OAuth 2 authorization error - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am trying to set a connection between my Google Drive and a project I am working, But this isn't the important part of this problem (I believe). To do so I needed an access token and a refresh token, anyways in order to get a refresh token from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
I did the steps necessary, but in the end I got this error when I tried to receive an Authorization Token.

> Access denied: The request sent by this app is invalid
>
> You cannot sign in because this app is sending an invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this issue.
> If you are one of the developers of this application, review the error details.
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

And we created the project and the OAuth2 key on Google Drive a really long time ago, so It can take a really long time to generate might not be an option.

I also tried this method as well.

## [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&response_type=token&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&scope=%7Bscope%7D)

which I founded from this link [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

What should I do so I can get myself a refresh token from OAuth2 Playground without any errors?
Thanks in advance for the help. :D