# Recieving a Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch Upon Trying to Connect to Google Drive

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-drive-api

I have been having an issue with using the google drive API with Java and Maven. I have added the drive-api to my project on the google cloud as well as to my codebase, but I receive a `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` whenever I attempt to connect using the default code.

I have tried modifying the code and looking to google documentation, without any luck. Here is my code:

```
package org.RESCINDED;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

// Part of this code is taken from the Google Drive quickstart.
@UtilityClass
public class DriveQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "default name";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json"; //originally called client secret I believe

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                        .setAccessType("offline").build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DriveQuickstart");

        FileList result = service.files().list().setPageSize(10).setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            logger.warning("No files found.");
        } else {
            logger.warning("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                logger.warning(file.getName() + " (" + file.getId() + ")\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=RESCINDED.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
```

And upon clicking the link in the correct account:

```
Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

EMAIL
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485644/3122175 work?