# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch Google Sign In

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

So, i want to setup google sign in feature using AWS Cognito, i already set up the client ID, Client Secret (In both AWS and Google developer console) and Redirect URI (In google developer console) to my local host.

i use this method to be signed in to pop out the google sign in
`const response = await Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: props.provider });`

When i tried login through google, it gives this error message

This is the error message
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=https://.....auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

Can someone help me with this?

I tried looking it up here
[Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

I already set up the callback URI and it still does not work.

Also i tried to set the callback URI to https://.....auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse in google developer, but it does not work

Comment: You must set the redirect URI when you make the HTTPS call to the authorize endpoint as well as configuring it on the identity provider.  They must match.