# Setting up OAuth 2.0 token for YouTube API using Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, postman, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'd like to set up an API call to schedule livestreams on my YouTube channel. At the moment I'd like to do some initial testing of calling the YouTube API using the Postman desktop app. But I'm struggling to get the authorization set-up (I have limited experience configuring authorization tokens).

In the Google Cloud Platform I have created my OAuth 2.0 client ID and secret. I've also set the following in Postman:

- Auth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
- Access token URL: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
- Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

(No idea whether these are correct -- I grabbed them from [this article](https://blog.postman.com/how-to-access-google-apis-using-oauth-in-postman/))

But when I click to get a new token, I get Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) I found the following answer:

> The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.
>
> Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & client secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

I'm presuming that this is referring to my Google Cloud Platform, but I cannot see any URIs listed or anywhere to enter URIs -- all I see is the client ID and client secret. Where I can specify the URIs? And how do I determine which URI to provide? (Eg does Postman automatically generate a URI for me?)

Any advice/suggestions on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated. (Expect follow-up comments as I'm sure this is the first of many errors I'll encounter getting this API set-up!)