# redirect_url_mismatch on getting token with authentication code

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, google-oauth

So I have this Front-end call

```
const handleSuccess = (response) => {
        console.log('login success');
        console.log('code: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        const authCode = response.code;
        fetch('https://localhost:7024/api/auth/google', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ AuthCode: authCode })
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log('success');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    const gglogin = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: handleSuccess,
        flow: 'auth-code',
    });
```

after login success it will send auth code to backend so backend can get tokenid and access token

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var tokenEndpoint = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
 var clientId = "<my client id>"; 
 var clientSecret = "<my client secret>";


 var tokenResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         { "code", request.AuthCode },
         { "client_id", clientId },
         { "client_secret", clientSecret },
         { "redirect_uri", "https://localhost:7024/api/auth/google" },
         { "grant_type", "authorization_code" }
     }));
 var tokenResponseContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("token data: " + tokenResponseContent);

 var tokenData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(tokenResponseContent);



 var idToken = tokenData.id_token;
 if (!tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     return BadRequest("Failed to exchange authorization code for ID token.");
 }
```

problem is, it logged this:

*token data: {
"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}*

Here are uri in my google cloud console
[image]

So how do I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: make sure port is open. try setting the uri with http instead of https for testing purpose. make sure there is no typo in the url. you're making the request from a backend, you could use a simple URI just for handling the OAuth2 flow, such as `http://localhost:7024/signin-google` (if `signin-google` were the path specified when registering your application in the Google API Console and intended to handle just the redirect). This would be separate from your general API endpoints. reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch