# Django-React google calendar API Error:redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, django, django-views, google-api, google-calendar-api

my `react` is in http://localhost:3000

my `django` is in http://localhost:8000

I'm trying to get the info form my calendar, i found this code in
[link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python)

```
class Test(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
        Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
        """
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

        creds = None
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists("token.json"):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "notes/credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                # Save the credentials for the next run
                with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                    token.write(creds.to_json())

        service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)

        # Call the Calendar API
        now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        print("Getting the upcoming 10 events")
        events_result = (
            service.events()
            .list(
                calendarId="primary",
                timeMin=now,
                maxResults=10,
                singleEvents=True,
                orderBy="startTime",
            )
            .execute()
        )
        events = events_result.get("items", [])

        if not events:
            print("No upcoming events found.")
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'No upcoming events found.'}, status=200)

        # Prepare data to be returned
        events_data = []
        for event in events:
            start = event["start"].get("dateTime", event["start"].get("date"))
            events_data.append({"start": start, "summary": event["summary"]})

        return JsonResponse({'events': events_data}, status=200)
```

but when i try to send the request using postman, i have an error

[image]

idk how to solve it. i have been reading and they tell me to add URLs to the Authorized JavaScript origins and the Authorized redirect URIs of the credential setting in the api, but nothing works.
my end objective is to create event in the calendar, but im tyring to get them for now and it does not work.

Comment: have you tried using the answer to [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch) it seems similar to what you're looking for

Comment: yes, it did not help. im not sure what else to do